# How to install MS hotfixes for XP on remote machines?

Tags: windows-xp, pstools, windows

How might I install a hotfix obtained from Microsoft to machines on the network?  The hotfix in question comes packaged as an .exe file.  I tried using psexec but the process never completes...I assume it's waiting for user input.  I'm not sure if there are any command-line switches for .exe hotfixes for silent installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time the option to install quietly is achieved by running the hotfix like this:

C:>Directory\hotfix.exe /Q

For a list of options supported by the hotfix try this:

C:>Directory\hotfix.exe /?